# PC error boot at all

Tags: 12.04

My workstations runs on a dual boot. It was working fine until I find an issue. As soon as I'm directed to the GRUB screen, where I select Ubuntu as usual. Now it wont boot but shows a black screen. I tried all possibilities but it returned with no luck. By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS. I had to re-install the OS when this happened to me at first. This is the second time it happened to me. What can I do to get this issue sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info. As mentioned, what was the other windows running on along side?? When you get black screen, how long does it stay.. meanwhile, does it shows any errors??

Comment: i dualbooted ubuntu 12.4 alongside windows 7 64 bit.and the black screen stays forever. doesn't show No errors.                            As soon as i enter into GRUB i selected ubuntu and then a light voilet colored screen comes (<<as ususal) and then just black screen,...